# Is the entire function with given condition constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity, analytic-functions

Let $f(z)=u+iv $ be entire function such that $v=u^2$. Is $f(z)$ constant?

My approach:

After some steps I got $|{e^{if(z)}}|=\frac{1}{e^{u^2}}.$ My question is,  can I claim $\frac{1}{e^{u^2}}$ is bounded?

Please help.

Comment: No, it's not bounded.  Let $u\to i\infty$  My first thought is to try the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Since $u$ is real-valued, we have $u^2 \geqslant 0$, and thus $e^{-u^2} \leqslant 1$.

Comment: WOW !! So $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I don't know the steps that give the equality that you mention. An alternative solution: Cauchy Riemann $u_x=v_y=(u^2)_y=2uu_y$, $u_y=-v_x=-2uu_x$. We deduce that $u_x=2u(-2uu_x)=-4u^2u_x$. So, $u_x(1+4u^2)=0$ and this implies $u$ is constant. Same argument with $v$.

Comment: What do you think about my approach? So if $u$  is constant, then $f$ must be constant.